# Is it possible to transfer images from iPhone to SD card directly?

Tags: iphone, sd-card

There is: http://www.apple.com/uk/shop/product/MD822ZM/A/lightning-to-sd-card-camera-reader

> It’s easy to download photos and videos from your digital camera to your iPad or iPad mini
>
> After you insert the SD card into the reader, your iPad automatically opens the Photos app, which lets you choose which photos and videos to import, then organises them into albums.

1. Description mentions only iPad (not iPhone)
2. Description mentions copying from SD card into the device

---

### What I'm trying to do?

Travelling. Don't want to take computer with me. I'd rather rather use a spacious SD card and use it a storage to offload photos / videos to keep my internal memory free (allowing me to shoot / record more)

**Possible?**

Answer (score 2):

From my own testing, I have verified that unfortunately, you can only use the SD card reader with the iPad. You can also only transfer photos/videos from the SD card to the iPad, not the other way around. I think these would be great features (take it from a 8GB iPhone 5c owner) to have, but unfortunately they are not available at this time.

You can send feedback to Apple at http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html as I have.

**Edit:** Now you can use the Lightning to SD Card adapter with the iPhone if you update to iOS 9.2! However, you can still only import from the SD card to the iOS Device and not from iOS Device to SD card. They have even updated the item description to mention iPhones at http://www.apple.com/ca/shop/product/MJYT2AM/A/lightning-to-sd-card-camera-reader. Still not sure about iPod touch (don't have one).

Comment: I agree. Send Apple [feedback](http://www.apple.com/feedback).  Twice in a year I had to haul a laptop on trips, just to be able to offload photos.   Dropbox could have worked on one trip, but would not have been economical on the other.

Comment: @MichalStefanow With iOS 9.2 you can now use the Lightning to SD Card adapter with all iOS devices. Update and try it out (if you have one!)

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can use something like this:
[https://www.amazon.com/TFZ-Certified-External-Lightning-Connector/dp/B00RRQSJ44](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00RRQSJ44)

greetings
Diego